# SAP .NET Connector RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration throws "Not Implemented" Exception

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

When I run the code below I get an exception

> "Not Implemented" saying that method has not been implemented.

at line 8:

```
RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(destinationConfig);
```

What is causing this? How can I fix it? I am attempting to connect to SAP using the SAP .NET Connector 3.0. This code is supposed to be registering a destination.

Here is my code that I am having issues with:

```
using SAP.Middleware.Connector

string destinationConfigName = "QA";
        IDestinationConfiguration destinationConfig = null;
        bool destinationIsInitialised = false;
        if (!destinationIsInitialised)
        {
            destinationConfig = new SAPDestinationConfig();
            destinationConfig.GetParameters(destinationConfigName);

            if (RfcDestinationManager.TryGetDestination(destinationConfigName) == null)
            {
                RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(destinationConfig);
                destinationIsInitialised = true;
            }
        }

public class SAPDestinationConfig:IDestinationConfiguration
    {
        public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;

        public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
        {
            RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Name, "QA");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_APPSERVERHOST"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_SYSTEMNUM"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_CLIENT"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_USERNAME"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_PASSWORD"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_CLIENT"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_LANGUAGE"]);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SAP_POOLSIZE"]);

            return parms;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the SAPDestinationConfig class come from? It's not mentioned in the official documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that. It is a class that I built that takes parameters for the connection (user name, pw, host, etc) and it is declared as SAPDestinationConfig:IDestinationConfiguration

Comment: Post edited to show class

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're throwing a NotImplementedException in your class and asking why the system is complaining that something is "Not Implemented"...? Or did I miss something here?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the implementation of the ChangeEventsSupported() method.  You should return either true or false, depending on if your implementation of the interface will support "Change" events.

Given the state of the above code, for instance, it should look like this:

```
public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1, but there's no need for your entire first sentence. I recommend you remove it with an edit. Best practice on StackOverflow is keep questions and answers straight to the point.